# How to prove $A\subsetneq C \iff A \cup B \subsetneq B \cup C$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I was asked to prove the following:

$A\subsetneq C \iff A \cup B \subsetneq B \cup C$

But, it seems wrong. Why can't I choose the following:

$B = C$ so $A$ is a strict subset of both, but the union with $B$ is equal to the union of $B$ and $C$

What am I missing?

**Fixed

Comment: You are not missing anything. The statement is wrong.

Comment: So, in order for it to be true - if I add the assumption that $B \neq C$, would it make it valid?

Comment: No, it would still be false.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$A = \{ 1 \}, B = \{ 2 \}, C = \{ 1, 2 \},$$

so $A \subsetneq C$, but $A \cup B = C = C \cup B$, hence $A \cup B \not\subsetneq B \cup C$.

The equivalence is wrong and you're not missing anything.

Comment: Yes, it's the same example i found by myself.. but the problem is that it's not a question that I should disprove,
If I add the assumption that $B \neq C$, would it make it correct?

Comment: In the given example, $B \neq C$ holds and it's still wrong.

Comment: Oh, yes, didn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the statement is wong.

You can also let $B$ be any superset of $ A \cup C$,

then we have $A \cup B=B= B \cup C$.

One possible condition is $B \cap (A \cup C) = \emptyset$ for the statement to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the statement is wrong in both directions. You have already seen that $A \subsetneq C$ does not implies $A \cup B \subsetneq  B \cup C$. Moreover, $A \cup B \subsetneq  B \cup C$ does not implies $A \subsetneq C$: take $A = \{0, 1\}$, $B = \{0\}$ and $C = \{1, 2\}$ for a counterexample.